# Change default terminal app in Visual Studio Code on Mac

Tags: terminal, iterm2, visual-studio-code

I want to change the default terminal app used by Visual Studio Code for Mac. I am thinking it is part of preferences or settings json, but unsure.

Answer (score 145, accepted):

Here's an example of how to make another terminal the default for VSCode, in this example I've downloaded iTerm2 and copied iTerm2 to Applications.

1. Code (Menu) > Preferences > User Settings

[image]

2. Edit settings.json `"terminal.external.osxExec": "iTerm.app"` and `"terminal.explorerKind": "external"`

[image]

3. Open in Terminal

[image]

4. iTerm is now default terminal launched from VSCode

[image]

Comment: in my end, i need to add this line in settings also "terminal.integrated.shell.osx": "zsh"

Comment: Will this be `iTerm2.app` those who are using iTerm2 ?

Comment: @ArupRakshit Nope, if you look in your applications folder, the app is called iTerm.app even if it's iTerm2.

Comment: @Underdog, current version of the command for 'zhn' is: 
,"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.osx": "zsh" . Yours is deprecated now.

Answer (score 108):

For those that want to change the **default integrated terminal** NOT just the external, and add `custom themes`, show which `git branch` you are on, and whether or not files need to be `staged or committed` [for example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gBzbW.png).

## Follow these **short** steps:

Make sure you have these installed:

> [iTerm2](https://iterm2.com/), [oh-my-zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/wiki/Installing-ZSH)

Install a `powerline font` *(I am using Menlo which is a nice looking and very popular font)*.

> Go [here](https://github.com/abertsch/Menlo-for-Powerline/blob/master/Menlo%20for%20Powerline.ttf) and click on `download`
>
> Open the file
>
> Click on `install font`
>
> *(Note: without this, vscode integrated terminal will not render themes correctly)*

Open the **.zshrc** file by running this command:

> cd ~ ; code .zshrc

Change **iTerm**'s theme to `agnoster`:

> Press `⌘f` to open search in the **.zshrc** file
>
> Type `ZSH_THEME`
>
> Search until you find the live code, **NOT** the commented out code :)
>
> Edit the code it so it looks like `ZSH_THEME="agnoster"`
>
> Save the file

**Open vscode settings** using shortcut:

> `⌘,`

Inside of vscode settings, you will see **two panels**. On the **right** panel paste this:

```
"terminal.external.osxExec": "iTerm.app",
"terminal.integrated.shell.osx": "/bin/zsh",
"terminal.integrated.fontFamily": "Menlo for Powerline"
```

Assuming the settings were **empty before**, it should **now look like this:**

```
{
    "terminal.external.osxExec": "iTerm.app",
    "terminal.integrated.shell.osx": "/bin/zsh",
    "terminal.integrated.fontFamily": "Menlo for Powerline"
}
```

Finished! Enjoy your new pimped out terminal

### -(Optional customization)-

If you want your prompt to display something other than your username such as a thunder bolt, like in [mine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zDWLp.png) or [anything you want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iy9lf.png)

Open **agnoster theme** by runnning this command:

> `cd ~/.oh-my-zsh/themes/ ; code agnoster.zsh-theme`

Open **search** by pressing:

> `⌘f`

Paste this in search bar:

> `prompt_segment black default "%(!.%{%F{yellow}%}.)$USER@%m"`

To change your what your prompt displays, edit **ONLY** this part:

> `$USER@%m`

**DO NOT CHANGE** this part:

> `prompt_segment black default "%(!.%{%F{yellow}%}.)`

In conclusion, the code should now look something like this:

> `prompt_segment black default "%(!.%{%F{yellow}%}.) Insert here whatever your heart desires"`
>
> *(Note: Technically you can change everything about your terminal prompt, but for the sake of keeping this short, and simple we only edited the username part)*

Comment: looks like you also bumped up the line height to give the text a little breathing room:

"terminal.integrated.lineHeight": 1.5

Comment: can you please elaborate: how do I add little icons like your lightning bold?

Comment: Just figured it out: `prompt_segment black default "%(!.%{%F{yellow}%}.)"$'\u26a1'`

Comment: The terminal only supports monospace fonts

Comment: It's working, but I recommend the following font: 
"terminal.integrated.fontFamily": "Cousine for Powerline"

Comment: @joshkmartinez with ZSH + iterm2 + Powerlevel10k, you should specify `MesloLGS NF`

Comment: @Juan Does this work for running IDE test cases?

Answer (score 24):

None of these answers fully worked for me. Here is what I changed to get it to work:

#### Select the default shell as `zsh`:

`CMD + SHIFT + P` to open up the command palette. Then type `Terminal: Select Default Shell`. You can then select `zsh`.
[image]

#### Change the terminal to use iTerm

[image]

#### Change the font family to use Powerlevel10k

[image]

#### Result

[image]

Comment: "terminal.integrated.fontFamily": "Hack Nerd Font" works like a charm.

Comment: Nothing else worked but this did thanks !

Comment: Note if you are having issues with "CMD + `" opening a new external iTerm window, make sure that you didn't set your iTerm hotkey to be that.

Answer (score 13):

I recently changed my terminal in VSCode to ozh, its just 1 step and 1 line.

1. Open `Command Palette` using `View > Command Palette`
   ( or simply `Command + Shift + P` )
2. add the following line to the `user settings`.

   `"terminal.integrated.shell.osx": "zsh"`

[image]

Comment: That does not answers the question. It's about changing the terminal used, not the shell.

Comment: It's still very helpful though. Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question as pointed out by @JoséCoelho

Answer (score 7):

well I know it's so late, but you could just change it by running command

```
Terminal: Select Default Shell
```

its so much easier

Comment: Kind of grave digging on posts but the above solutions would be helpful for specific use-cases.

Comment: This answer is super awesome. Thanks @kent.

Comment: I can't find that command - I think it may now be Terminal: Select Default Profile, although I'm not sure as I don't have it working

Answer (score 3):

From visual studio code blog:

```
// 64-bit cmd it available, otherwise 32-bit
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows":"C:\\Windows\\sysnative\\cmd.exe"
// 64-bit PowerShell if available, otherwise 32-bit
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows":"C:\\Windows\\sysnative\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe"
// Git Bash
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe"
// Bash on Ubuntu (on Windows)
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Windows\\sysnative\\bash.exe"
```

Reference: [Integrated Terminal](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal)

Answer (score 1):

In vscode `settings.json` add:

```
"terminal.integrated.profiles.osx": {
    "zsh": null
},
```

Answer (score -34):

No. But you can vote for this feature here: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/293070-visual-studio-code

Comment: For anyone reading this, the correct answer is further down. Change setting `"terminal.external.osxExec": "iTerm.app"`

Comment: You can change the external terminal to iterm2 (which opens a separate window, not inside vscode), but not the integrated shell. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44163545/1316649

Comment: This 'was' the correct answer for some time, but have adjusted the accepted answer.