# Unable to use iTerm2 in vs code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I tried to use iTerm2 as the external terminal in vs code but somehow it failed. Here is my user settings:

```
{
"workbench.colorTheme": "Material Theme",
"window.zoomLevel": 0,
"editor.fontSize": 14,
"python.pythonPath": "/ommitted/dl/proj/bin/python3.6", 
"workbench.iconTheme": "eq-material-theme-icons",
"terminal.explorerKind": "external",
"terminal.external.osxExec": "/Applications/iTerm.app/Contents/MacOS/iTerm2"
}
```

The above settings returned the following result:
[image]

Which I expected a Python 3.6 from a virtualenv environment, as shown in the setting. Is there anything wrong with my setting? Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried replacing iTerm2 with iterm?  that works on my machine and the name of the app is iTerm.

Comment: @jmh I tried ```"terminal.external.osxExec": "iTerm.app"```, but didn't work:/

Comment: Find your answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43900516/integrated-terminal-setting-vs-code-and-iterm-returns-zsh/44163545