# Why isn't vscode using my default iTerm2 profile?

Tags: visual-studio-code, iterm2

I know I can use settings like `"terminal.integrated.fontFamily"` to change the font and font size, but I'm confused why vscode isn't just loading my default iTerm2 profile? Shouldn't it be doing that?

I'm just using the default settings: [image]

I already have vscode using iTerm:
[image]

But when I open the shell in vscode the font type is totally different.

Do I really need to maintain a separate vscode config or can vscode just load iTerm profiles?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Integrated Terminal Setting VS Code and iTerm returns zsh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43900516/integrated-terminal-setting-vs-code-and-iterm-returns-zsh)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using "zsh" or "Oh my zsh", you can add the below line based on your OS to the VS Code settings.json:

Linux:
"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.linux": "zsh"

macOS:
"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.osx": "zsh"

Windows:
"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "zsh"