# How do I set ZSH to be the default shell instead of bash in the Visual Code studio integrated terminal on Mac

Tags: terminal, visual-studio-code, zsh

I've tried changing the settings to:

```
"terminal.integrated.shell.linux": "usr/bin/zsh"
```

and also

```
"terminal.integrated.shell.linux": "/bin/zsh",
```

But I can't get it to work. Cheers

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29957456/change-default-terminal-app-in-visual-studio-code-on-mac last answer. Ctrl-shift-P "Terminal: Select Default Shell"   and you will have to restart but then it is saved.

Comment: Thanks, I don't want to launch another application, I want zsh to be the default in the VS interface.

Comment: That is what it does, resets the default terminal.

Comment: In the example it sets the default terminal to be the iTerm app:

    "terminal.external.osxExec": "iTerm.app"

I want to run zsh so i need to change the default linux bash shell

   "terminal.integrated.shell.linux": "/bin/bash"

I just can't seem to find the right path to use for zsh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was trying to change to change the linux integrated shell! Whoops.

The user setting for Mac is:

```
"terminal.integrated.shell.osx": "/bin/zsh",
```

Comment: This has been deprecated and should now read: `"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.osx": "zsh"` see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/67472427/5234788