# ZSH And VSCode - Default Shells

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code, zsh, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I've started setting up ZSH for VSCode. It worked for a small bit, but then it changed to Git Bash (my previous default shell). I tried changing the shell back to ZSH, but it didn't display in the list of opinions. Though, it does display WSL, which displays a completely different theme

My theme (in windows terminal, unbuntu, ect): 
[image: My theme]
The theme that is in VSCode: 
[image: WSL defaulted theme]

I've tried adding this to my `settings.json`:

```json
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "/bin/zsh",
```

But it says: "The terminal process failed to launch: Path to shell executable "\bin\zsh" does not exist."

How can I fix this (change the default shell back to ZSH)?

Comment: Have you tried something like `"terminal.integrated.shell.windows":  "wsl.exe -d Ubuntu-20.04 -e /bin/zsh"`.

Answer (score 50):

Try `which zsh` to confirm the path of your zsh executable. You might be having path error.

[image: which zsh]

*Or Try the GUI way.*

1. Open Command Palette

Windows - `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `P`

Mac - `⌘` + `Shift` + `P`

2. Search For `Terminal: Select Default Shell` and select it.

[image: Command Palette]

3. See the list of available shells and select one. If you cannot see zsh here, then you might have some configuration issues with zsh.

[image: Available Shells]

It also likely that the zsh installation/configuration error caused your entry in `settings.json` file to be invalid. Once you have selected the shell, hit `ctrl` + `~` or `⌘` + `J` to open the terminal window and see the results. If you already opened a terminal then you would have to trash it or open another one.

You could also open your `settings.json` and see or add the following entry directly.

```
// Edit July 2021 - New Updated Snippet
"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.osx": "zsh"

// Now deprecated
"terminal.integrated.shell.osx": "/bin/zsh"
```

Comment: `terminal.integrated.shell.osx` has been deprecated for `terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.osx` (`shell` to `defaultProfile`) but the new rule instead defaults to bash (at the time of this post)

Comment: It worked! Thank you. In my VS code on Ubuntu the command is: Terminal: Select Default Profile

Comment: editing settings.json and then restarting code worked for me. thanks.

Comment: i don't have the /bin/zsh even listed (ubuntu), any idea why and how do  i add it?

Answer (score 34):

Looks like it has changed slightly on Macs.

Mac - `⌘` + `Shift` + `P`

Type "Terminal: Select Default Profile", and select it.

[image]

Then you will see this:

[image]

Choose bash or whatever, and then you must close and restart VS Code.

Comment: Not on Mac, but for all. Terminals now have profiles and OS-specific settings.

Comment: Key thing is to restart VS Code, not to force reload the window

Answer (score 18):

Here's the solution:

`terminal.integrated.shell.osx` has been deprecated for `terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.osx` (`shell` to `defaultProfile`) but the new rule instead defaults to bash (at the time of this post)

What actually happens is this: (got it by using the GUI instead) - it's the path. `terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.osx` actually works, but the value has to be changed from `/bin/zsh` to `zsh`.

So the setting should be `"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.osx": "zsh"` instead of `"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.osx": "/bin/zsh"`.

Also note the language changed from Default `shell` to `defaultProfile`.

Comment: Is this already working? Because the zsh profile appears but unless I use the deprecated command it keeps opening bash as the first option.

Comment: It is working. Not sure what your exact challenge is, but I noticed I had to close and reopen all terminal instances in my saved workspaces - since they were all defaulting to bash after the change - but after that everything works fine.

Comment: `defaultProfile` saved me :)

Answer (score 8):

open "~/.config/Code/User/settings.json"

add your default shell depending on you OS:

```
"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.linux": "zsh"
"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.osx": "zsh"
"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "zsh"
```

Comment: For me, this was the path to settings: `/Library/Application Support/Code/User/settings.json`

Comment: Depending on how you installed VS Code on a Mac, it may also be located at `~/Library/Application Support/Code/User/settings.json`