# Changing the external console used by launch.json

Tags: terminal, visual-studio-code, iterm2

I'm trying to get the output from the process I am debugging to display in iTerm.

I have added the following lines to my UserSettings file

```
"terminal.external.osxExec": "iTerm.app",
"terminal.explorerKind": "external",
```

And when I select `open in terminal` from within Visual Studio Code it does indeed open with iTerm.

However when I set `"externalConsole": true,` in my `launch.json` file, the output still shows up in a new `Terminal.app` window.

How do I get the debugging output to show up in iTerm? Do I need to change more settings?

---

I have read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29957456/9614249). The steps I took above came from answers to that question but my problem is specifically in getting the debugging output to iTerm.