# Python and Data Science tutorial for visual studio isn't working as expected

Tags: python, pandas, visual-studio, csv

[image: Picture of workspace]

I have followed the instructions and can't figure out what the error is.

Here is the parser message:
ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 3, saw 2

Here is the error message:
{
"name": "ParserError",
"message": "Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 3, saw 2\n",
"stack": "\u001b[0;31m---------------------------------------------------------------------------\u001b[0m\n\u001b[0;31mParserError\u001b[0m                               Traceback (most recent call last)\n\u001b[1;32m/home/luke/Documents/hello_ds/hello.ipynb Cell 1'\u001b[0m in \u001b[0;36m<cell line: 3>\u001b[0;34m()\u001b[0m\n\u001b[1;32m      1\u001b[0m \u001b[39mimport\u001b[39;00m \u001b[39mpandas\u001b[39;00m \u001b[39mas\u001b[39;00m \u001b[39mpd\u001b[39;00m\n\u001b[1;32m      2\u001b[0m \u001b[39mimport\u001b[39;00m \u001b[39mnumpy\u001b[39;00m \u001b[39mas\u001b[39;00m \u001b[39mnp\u001b[39;00m\n\u001b[0;32m----> 3\u001b[0m data \u001b[39m=\u001b[39m pd\u001b[39m.\u001b[39;49mread_csv(\u001b[39m'\u001b[39;49m\u001b[39mdata.csv\u001b[39;49m\u001b[39m'\u001b[39;49m)\n\nFile \u001b[0;32m~/miniconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py:311\u001b[0m, in \u001b[0;36mdeprecate_nonkeyword_arguments..decorate..wrapper\u001b[0;34m(*args, **kwargs)\u001b[0m\n\u001b[1;32m    305\u001b[0m \u001b[39mif\u001b[39;00m \u001b[39mlen\u001b[39m(args) \u001b[39m>\u001b[39m num_allow_args:\n\u001b[1;32m    306\u001b[0m     warnings\u001b[39m.\u001b[39mwarn(\n\u001b[1;32m    307\u001b[0m         msg\u001b[39m.\u001b[39mformat(arguments\u001b[39m=\u001b[39marguments),\n\u001b[1;32m    308\u001b[0m         \u001b[39mFutureWarning\u001b[39;00m,\n\u001b[1;32m    309\u001b[0m         stacklevel\u001b[39m=\u001b[39mstacklevel,\n\u001b[1;32m    310\u001b[0m     )\n\u001b[0;32m--> 311\u001b[0m \u001b[39mreturn\u001b[39;00m func(\u001b[39m*\u001b[39;49margs, \u001b[39m*\u001b[39;49m\u001b[39m*\u001b[39;49mkwargs)\n\nFile \u001b[0;32m~/miniconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers/readers.py:680\u001b[0m, in \u001b[0;36mread_csv\u001b[0;34m(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, skipfooter, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, cache_dates, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, doublequote, escapechar, comment, encoding, encoding_errors, dialect, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, on_bad_lines, delim_whitespace, low_memory, memory_map, float_precision, storage_options)\u001b[0m\n\u001b[1;32m    665\u001b[0m kwds_defaults \u001b[39m=\u001b[39m _refine_defaults_read(\n\u001b[1;32m    666\u001b[0m     dialect,\n\u001b[1;32m    667\u001b[0m     delimiter,\n\u001b[0;32m   (...)\u001b[0m\n\u001b[1;32m    676\u001b[0m     defaults\u001b[39m=\u001b[39m{\u001b[39m"\u001b[39m\u001b[39mdelimiter\u001b[39m\u001b[39m"\u001b[39m: \u001b[39m"\u001b[39m\u001b[39m,\u001b[39m\u001b[39m"\u001b[39m},\n\u001b[1;32m    677\u001b[0m )\n\u001b[1;32m    678\u001b[0m kwds\u001b[39m.\u001b[39mupdate(kwds_defaults)\n\u001b[0;32m--> 680\u001b[0m \u001b[39mreturn\u001b[39;00m _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)\n\nFile \u001b[0;32m~/miniconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers/readers.py:581\u001b[0m, in \u001b[0;36m_read\u001b[0;34m(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)\u001b[0m\n\u001b[1;32m    578\u001b[0m     \u001b[39mreturn\u001b[39;00m parser\n\u001b[1;32m    580\u001b[0m \u001b[39mwith\u001b[39;00m parser:\n\u001b[0;32m--> 581\u001b[0m     \u001b[39mreturn\u001b[39;00m parser\u001b[39m.\u001b[39;49mread(nrows)\n\nFile \u001b[0;32m~/miniconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers/readers.py:1254\u001b[0m, in \u001b[0;36mTextFileReader.read\u001b[0;34m(self, nrows)\u001b[0m\n\u001b[1;32m   1252\u001b[0m nrows \u001b[39m=\u001b[39m validate_integer(\u001b[39m"\u001b[39m\u001b[39mnrows\u001b[39m\u001b[39m"\u001b[39m, nrows)\n\u001b[1;32m   1253\u001b[0m \u001b[39mtry\u001b[39;00m:\n\u001b[0;32m-> 1254\u001b[0m     index, columns, col_dict \u001b[39m=\u001b[39m \u001b[39mself\u001b[39;49m\u001b[39m.\u001b[39;49m_engine\u001b[39m.\u001b[39;49mread(nrows)\n\u001b[1;32m   1255\u001b[0m \u001b[39mexcept\u001b[39;00m \u001b[39mException\u001b[39;00m:\n\u001b[1;32m   1256\u001b[0m     \u001b[39mself\u001b[39m\u001b[39m.\u001b[39mclose()\n\nFile \u001b[0;32m~/miniconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers/c_parser_wrapper.py:225\u001b[0m, in \u001b[0;36mCParserWrapper.read\u001b[0;34m(self, nrows)\u001b[0m\n\u001b[1;32m    223\u001b[0m \u001b[39mtry\u001b[39;00m:\n\u001b[1;32m    224\u001b[0m     \u001b[39mif\u001b[39;00m \u001b[39mself\u001b[39m\u001b[39m.\u001b[39mlow_memory:\n\u001b[0;32m--> 225\u001b[0m         chunks \u001b[39m=\u001b[39m \u001b[39mself\u001b[39;49m\u001b[39m.\u001b[39;49m_reader\u001b[39m.\u001b[39;49mread_low_memory(nrows)\n\u001b[1;32m    226\u001b[0m         \u001b[39m# destructive to chunks\u001b[39;00m\n\u001b[1;32m    227\u001b[0m         data \u001b[39m=\u001b[39m _concatenate_chunks(chunks)\n\nFile \u001b[0;32m~/miniconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx:805\u001b[0m, in \u001b[0;36mpandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.read_low_memory\u001b[0;34m()\u001b[0m\n\nFile \u001b[0;32m~/miniconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx:861\u001b[0m, in \u001b[0;36mpandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_rows\u001b[0;34m()\u001b[0m\n\nFile \u001b[0;32m~/miniconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx:847\u001b[0m, in \u001b[0;36mpandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._tokenize_rows\u001b[0;34m()\u001b[0m\n\nFile \u001b[0;32m~/miniconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx:1960\u001b[0m, in \u001b[0;36mpandas._libs.parsers.raise_parser_error\u001b[0;34m()\u001b[0m\n\n\u001b[0;31mParserError\u001b[0m: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 3, saw 2\n"
}

Comment: Please change the error text here to remove all the control codes.

Comment: Sorry but I don't know what a control code is. Is there a setting to do that on visual studio?

Comment: All those \u001b[0;32m, etc, characters. They make it very difficult to understand the actual error message. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62503627/how-to-solve-weird-characters-in-visual-studio-codes-output-console-for-cmake-b