# Is it possible to use iTerm2 on macOS as external console in VSCode C/C++ debugger?

Tags: c, gdb, vscode-debugger, iterm2

I'm trying to debug a **C program** inside **VSCode**, but in this case I need to enter some data into the standard input, so I added this parameter inside my `launch.json`:

```json
"externalConsole": true
```

This parameter is useful because it allows me to open the **Terminal macOS application** with the **C** program that I'm debugging.

Something like this:
[C Debugging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4mQt.png)

But I want **iTerm2** as the terminal to be opened in order to enter the information that I want inside my program.

In other posts I have found that I need to modify the `terminal.external.osxExec` parameter inside my settings in order an specific app, but actually I have set this parameter pointing to the **iTerm2**, but it doesn't work.

Could someone have a solution for this?

Comment: Did the other posts you look at include [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29957456/change-default-terminal-app-in-visual-studio-code-on-mac)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change default terminal app in Visual Studio Code on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29957456/change-default-terminal-app-in-visual-studio-code-on-mac)

Comment: No, none of these links solve the issue. :(